# Using the IPAddress Gem As a Custom Field in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid3

I'm trying to use [IPAddress](https://github.com/bluemonk/ipaddress) as a [custom field](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#custom_fields) for a Mongoid Document by monkey patching the serialization methods to the IPAddress module and I just can't seem to get it...

```
class Computer
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :ip_address, type: IPAddress
end

module IPAddress
  def mongoize
    to_string
  end

  def self.mongoize(object)
    object.to_string
  end

  def self.demongoize(string)
    IPAddress.new string
  end

  def self.evolve(object)
    object.to_string
  end
end
```

Here's what I got right this second... but I've tried lots of other ways and just can't find one that works. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What errors are you getting? What versions are you using? Also in the Computer class aren't you missing include Mongoid::Document?

Comment: You are missing a .new inside demongoize (`IPAddress.new(string)`)